# Hibernate Self-Join special case of "getting error failed to lazily... No Session"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

The error "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role (...) could not initialize proxy -- no Session" is discussed extensively in SO but I am wondering if a self-join (for example, manager/employee relationship where managers are also employees) is a special situation. I am frankly baffled by the error and the explanations of it but I thought I would start with this "special case" question since it seems to me that it might be and so answers to how to deal with the error may not apply to self-joins.I will also mention that I am using Spring MVC and the error occurs when I try to show a manager with all of their employees.

Comment: For what it is worth, my particular problem was solved (apparently) by adding fetch=FetchType.EAGER. It sort of makes sense to me but the answers for this kind of problem seem to usually be more complex. I also threw a Transactional -- no idea at this point whether I have superfluous stuff.

Answer (score 0):

An entity object created by hibernate cannot be expected to behave normally outside `Service` and `DAO` layers if it is lazily loaded. This is because such an object is a proxy created by hibernate and the fields are loaded only when needed as long as the proxy remains connected to the underlying database (hibernate session). Once you leave the `Service` or `DAO` layers, e.g getting an object using `DAO` layer and try to use it in the controller, the object is disconnected and any fields which haven't been fetched will not be able to get the data from the database. Moreover, you will not be able to save the object back to the database (You could argue that saving can be done but i I am not certain if it can be done properly fro a complex object).

The solution is to eagerly load the object, meaning that all fields should be loaded by hibernate when the object is created (this is a costly operation).

(Better) Alternative solution is to move your logic in the controller to the service layer.

Comment: What does moving logic in the controller to the service layer entail? To be frank, many of the answers to questions about Hibernate I have read in SO are to abstract/sophisticated to follow.